Determining the simultaneous rank of two matrices
I am reading the article: 
[Gesmundo, Fulvio, Alessandro Oneto, and Emanuele Ventura. "Partially symmetric variants of Comon's problem via simultaneous rank." SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications 40.4 (2019): 1453-1477.], 
which gives the notion of simultaneous rank of tensors. Below I give the defintion for real symmetric matrices.
Defnition: Let $X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be two symmetric matrice, the simultaneous rank of $X,Y$ is defined as the minimal number of rank one symmetric matrices such that $X,Y$ can be represented as the linear combination of these rank one matrices, formally，
\begin{equation}
rank_s(X,Y)=\min\{r:X,Y \in span(v_1 v_1^T,\dotsm,v_r v_r^T),v_j \in \mathbb{R}^n,j=1,\dots,r\}.
\end{equation}
I notice that the above definition may be viewed as a generalized simultaneously diagonalization of $X,Y$, in the sense that
\begin{equation}
X=V DV^T,\quad Y=V \Lambda V^T
\end{equation}
where $V=[v_1,\dots, v_r] \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ and $D,\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ are diagonal. And we have
\begin{equation}
\max(rank(X),rank(Y)) \leq rank_s(X,Y) \leq rank(X)+rank(Y).
\end{equation}
And my question is: Is there an approach to determine the simultaneous rank of two symmetric matrices $X,Y$? JUST Like one can use the Gauss elimination to determine the rank of a matrix.

The simultaneous diagonalization approach will work for real symmetric matrices, you can just use $A + \alpha I$ for large enough $\alpha$ (larger then the negated minimal eigenvalue of $A$) and invoke the standard simultaneous diagonalization for $A + \alpha I$ and $B$. After that we have a basis where both $A$ and $B$ are diagonal, and one can prove that the simultaneous rank would be the number of nonzero pairs of corresponding diagonal entries.
In fact, this proves that $\operatorname{rank}_s(A, B) = \max \{\operatorname{rank}(\alpha A + \beta B) \mid \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}, (\alpha, \beta) \neq (0,0)\}$, and you can find the right hand side by applying Gaussian elimination to the symbolic matrix $(\alpha A + \beta B)$ (considered as a matrix over the field of rational functions in $\alpha,\beta$).
